# Create dynamic routing with Express based on handlebars files

Tags: javascript, express, get, routes, handlebars.js

I'm trying to get a page name from a GET request with express so i will be able to load a handlebar file based on this name.

**The problem is** when a page is loaded express keep getting a requests from assets for example - style.css, bundle.js...

is there any way to get the requested name page only?

Here is an example of what i'm trying to do:

```
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
   let pageCalled = req.originalUrl;
   let page = pageCalled.replace(' ', '').replace(/\//g, '');

   if (page === '') page = 'index';

   if (fs.exists(`./views/pages/${page}.hbs`)) {
       res.render(`pages/${page}`);
   } else {
       res.render(`pages/404`);
}})
```

Comment: change wildcard '*' to the proper regex https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex in [express routing](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html)

```js
app.get(/.*html$/, (req, res) => {
  // do what you need
})
```

Comment: you can create more complex regex to handle such cases

Comment: give me example of urls that you want to handle

Comment: `/\/?(about\/?)?$/` - try this regex

Comment: it can be as complex as you want

Comment: you can create regexp based on variables

Comment: `/^([^.]+)$/` https://regex101.com/r/eLxYns/2 try this one to skip all files with extensions